# Approaches for animating swinging bridge?

Tags: animation, workflow, lattice

I tried animating a small, very simple rope bridge, swinging against the wind. I tried using a combination of lattice deform, soft-body lattices, soft-body ropes with attachment vertexes on horizontal ropes, a wind source that is animated in locrot and str, and a turbulence source with the same.
But the result was not exactly good. Is there a better way to approach this? Should I try animating it manually?

[image: Setup]

Comment: Did you consider using cloth simulation? Starting with a rope, pinned on both sides, and once you get that working try adding hooked ropes downwards, later eventually adding boards. Sounds easy, needs some trial and error though, would try, but can't at the moment. So i can only suggest it for now.

Comment: Have you tried with the wave modifier ?

Comment: @Xylvier yes that's what I had done, actually NURBS with the soft body modifier and a solidify, it worked fine for it, but the problem was that the wind didn't move the lattice in a realistic manner, only side to side, and it looked kinda stiff. But I might try adding a wave modifier, I haven't thought of that.